# Can you please tell me to to add comment to post by using post id in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I want to know how to add comment on post by using post id.

Here I am showing all the comment not specific post comment. I think I should have to add code in controller to do this.

Here is the comment and post model

Comment

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    namespace Post.Models
    {
        public class Comments
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Comment { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [RegularExpression(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide Valid email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string dateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    
            public int PostId { get; set; }
            public Post Post { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Post

```
using Post.Models;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BlogTutorial.ViewModel
{
    public class PostVM
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please provide subtitle")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide Valid email")]
        public string SubTitle { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Cover image for blog post")]
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public void SharedLayOutData()
{
    ViewBag.Post = db.Tbl_Post;
    ViewBag.Comments = db.Tbl_Comments;
    ViewBag.Profile = db.Tbl_Profile.FirstOrDefault();
}

public IActionResult AddComment()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddComment(Comments mycomment)
{
    db.Tbl_Comments.Add(mycomment);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Post", "Home");
}
```

Add Post

```
public IActionResult AddPost()
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoginFlag") != null)
    {
        DisplayData();
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        //return RedirectToAction("Login", "Admin");
        return Redirect("/Admin/Login?ReturnUrl=/Admin/AddPost");
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddPost(PostVM myPost)
{
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoginFlag") != null)
    {
        DisplayData();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string ImageName = myPost.Image.FileName.ToString();
            var FolderPath = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "images");
            var CompletePicPath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, ImageName);
            myPost.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(CompletePicPath, FileMode.Create));

            Post post = new Post();
            post.Title = myPost.Title;
            post.SubTitle = myPost.SubTitle;
            post.Date = myPost.Date;
            post.Slug = myPost.Slug;
            post.Content = myPost.Content;
            post.Image = ImageName;

            db.Tbl_Post.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Admin");
}
```

Here is the view

```
@using Post.Models
@using System.Web;
@model Post
@{
    IEnumerable<Comments> mycomments = ViewBag.Comments;
}
<!-- Blog entry -->
  <div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin w3-white">
    <img src="~/images/@Model.Image" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <hr>
      <h3><b>@Model.Title</b></h3>
      <hr>
      <h5>@Model.SubTitle ,<span class="w3-opacity">@Model.Date</span></h5>
      <hr>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
      <p>
          @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content))
      </p>
      <div class="w3-row">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container comment_section">
          <section class="comments_top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
             
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-12 pb-4">
                        <h1>Comments</h1>
                        @foreach(var item in mycomments){
                        <div class="comment mt-4 text-justify float-left">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yTFUilP.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle" width="40" height="40">
                            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
                            <span>@item.dateTime</span>
                            <br>
                            <p>@item.Comment</p>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-4 offset-md-1 offset-sm-1 col-12 mt-4">
                     
                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Please tell me how to retrieve comments on a specific post by the post id

Comment: A bit confused what is your problem, can you try to revise the question? Do you mean you want to query the comments under the post by postId?

Comment: i want to add comments on post